# How to count number of strings in a list

Tags: python

My needs check windows process number.

```
import sys
import os
import commands

ip = sys.argv[5]
val = sys.argv[1]
oid = "HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName"
cmd = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,oid)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
if r_c != 0:
    print "C - snmpwalk is Error."
else:
    for i in r_e.split('\n'):
    a  =  i.split(':')[-1].strip(' "')
    print a
```

Result：

```
conhost.exe
conhost.exe
conhost.exe
conhost.exe
fdhost.exe
cmd.exe
fdhost.exe
```

I hope the result is. I do not know how to achieve it.

```
if sys.argv[1] <5:#count(conhost.exe)
    print "critical -"
else:
    print "OK - "
```

How the statistics of my results? conhost.exe 4 conhost.exe 1 conhost.exe 1

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can you please specify the question more precisely? Its not clear what you wish to ask.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of times that `conhost.exe` occurs in the output of `snmpwalk` and print "critical -" if the number is less than 5?

Comment: How the statistics of the number of my results?.

Answer (score 1):

```
# replace here
else:
    processes = r_e.split('\n')
    programs = 0
    for program in processes:
        programFile = program.split(':')[-1].strip(' "')
        # the first argument you pass to the program should be conhost.exe
        if programFile == sys.argv[1]:
            programs = programs + 1
    if programs < 5 :#count(conhost.exe)
        print "critical: running less than 5 times:", sys.argv[1] 
    else:
        print "OK"
```

second version

```
# replace here
else:
    processes = r_e.split('\n')
    processes = map(lambda program: program.split(':')[-1].strip(' "'), processes)
    if processes.count(sys.argv[1]) < 5 :#count(conhost.exe)
        print "critical: running less than 5 times:", sys.argv[1] 
    else:
        print "OK"
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers you find useful.  Accept them by clicking the grey arrow beneath the answer score box